# How to remove access from Microsoft Fabric workspace

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I see how to add users to a Fabric workspace - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/get-started/give-access-workspaces) - but how do I remove users from a Fabric workspace?

Answer (score 0):

aha - if you click on 'manage access' > person, one of the options in the role dropdown is 'remove'.

[image]